# NumberFormatException - trying to parse json, by edittview, edittview to char array

Tags: java, android, json

im trying to parse JSON to android, and after parsing json, i want to change the id that gets inputted in Edittext, to char array..

Im getting a `NumberFormatException`

I hope this isnt a stupid question, but where lies the problem? And why?

> 10-24 11:10:06.135  24572-24572/android.pd.packed.droid
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "54034013ddff"

```
 ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext)).setText(message); 
  edt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
 String rop = edt.getText().toString();
        char[] d = rop.toCharArray();
   checker = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TAG);
   JSONObject a = checker.getJSONObject((int) (Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(rop.valueOf(d).toCharArray())))-1);
```

Comment: String rop = edt.getText().toString().trim();
Try this ? May be

Comment: long can't contain letters so 54034013ddff must be String instead of long

Comment: I wanted to convert it to a Char Array[]

Comment: Use regex `\\d+` to split the numbers and then use the integer to perform operation. Also i suggest that you should use `try...catch` block. It is a good practice to code.

Comment: What exactly is TAG_TAG? That last line is... ugly :P

Answer (score 0):

Quit simple. If you use Long.parseLong("SomeStringThatIsNotANumber") you have to catch the exception by

```
try{
    //Long.parseLong("1231dff");
}catch(NumberFormatException nex){
    //Do what ever make sense
}
```

or check the content of the string before.

Comment: But the OP doesn't want an issue here - they want to parse the value, which looks like hex to me. So I suspect they want to parse it *as* hex.

Comment: The numbers inputted in the edittext are not always numbers.. I need AB1004AB numbers like these

Comment: @segnik: Well if they're not numbers, why are you trying to parse them as numbers? Don't treat non-numbers as numbers! Or do you mean they're hex values rather than decimal? You're being very unclear...

Comment: I was under the impression, i could convert anyinput to characters.. Cuz the numbers i need to be able to parse are like: 100AD or 999.999.999 or 10-DP

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");  
Matcher m = p.matcher("There are more than -2 and less than 12 numbers here"); 
while (m.find()) {  
System.out.println(m.group()); 
}
```

This will print -2 and 12